# How to access columns with blank space in column name with pyodbc

Tags: pyodbc

I have a database (Navision) with tons of tables and columns containing blank spaces.
How to access them a pyodbc way (like row.column)

```
cursor.execute("select [album id], photo_id from [my photos] where user_id=1")
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

this works

```
print(row.photo_id)
print(row[0]
```

those of course doesn't work

```
print(row.[album id])
print(row."album id")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access values by column name via the `__getattribute__` method of the `Row` object:

```python
row = crsr.execute("SELECT 'foo' AS [my column]").fetchone()
print(row.__getattribute__('my column'))  ## foo
```

Comment: It's not too nice, but nevertheless it works. But I still prefer then the row[n] notation

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend aliasing the field in the query. So:

```
cursor.execute("select [album id] as album_id, photo_id from [my photos] where user_id=1")
```

Then it'll be fairly trivial to get the value you need by referencing the alias:

```
print(row.album_id)
```